# How to include "require" in PhpStorm for my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phpstorm, js-test-driver, canvg

I am using the line `canvg('canvas', svg);` in my code. This means I need canvg.js.

I have included canvg.js in my html header. However it gives me an error that "require is undefined".

For those that don't know the first two lines of canvg.js are:

```
var RGBColor = require('rgbcolor'),
    StackBlur = require('stackblur-canvas');
```

This first showed up in my console as an error. This wasn't really a problem as the code still worked.

Now that I am on to testing though the errors cause the tests not to run. This is an issue.

```
error loading file: /test/tests/Dependencies/canvg.js:4: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I went to https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js and copied and pasted the code to a file called require236.js and saved it in my project.

I then went to my main.html an added my `<script src="require236.js"></script>`
right before canvg is loaded.

I got these errors in the console:

```
 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return f}
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
   at makeError (require236.js:168)
   at intakeDefines (require236.js:1254)
   at require236.js:1452
require236.js:143 Uncaught Error: Module name "rgbcolor" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at makeError (require236.js:168)
  at Object.localRequire [as require] (require236.js:1436)
  at requirejs (require236.js:1797)
  at canvg.js:4
```

And my tests do not run with that file as a dependency.

https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch says

> To avoid the error:
>
> Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API.
>
> Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have
>   define() calls in them.
>
> If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes named 
>   modules, and that an anonymous module that will have the same name as one 
>   of the modules in that file is not loaded.
>
> If the problem is the use of loader plugins or anonymous
>   modules but the RequireJS optimizer is not used for file bundling, use
>   the RequireJS optimizer.
>
> If the problem is the var define lint approach, use /*global define */ (no 
>   space before "global") comment style instead.

But I honestly do not understand how they expect to include it and where. Please use simple English words (or just show a code sample) if you understand it enough to explain it.

I am running from PhpStorm. I am testing with jsTestDriver. I must be declaring it wrong somehow but I have no clue how and why require.js is giving me such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that the file you have included is not supposed to be run in browser, as it uses the **CommonJS** syntax that can only be used in server-side code run by **node.js**.

You have to make sure to include the browser version of your library that doesn't have any `require()` calls, like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvg/dist/browser/canvg.min.js"></script>
```

see https://github.com/canvg/canvg#usage-on-the-browser

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)